# Need Django GUI IDE

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, rdf

I am new with Django. I need to quickly develop a sophisticated GUI for a Django project. My underlying database is resource description framework (RDF).  Is there any Eclipse IDE available for quick Django GUI development? Or is there any other GUI development tool (provides widgets) available for Django based project?

Comment: for Eclipse: [PyDev](http://pydev.org) or [PyDev as Eclipse plugin](http://pydev.org/download.html#urls-for-pydev-as-eclipse-plugin)

Comment: GUI is a term more for desktops, frontend is for web, for more see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface

Comment: Wingware comes with Django managing features, it's debugger even shows you where in templates the error occured.

Answer (score 0):

JetBrains has a Product for Python developers with Django support.
Its not for free but you can try it for 30 days.

https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/

Answer (score 0):

Django is a web framework. It doesn't have a GUI. Though there are many IDEs that support Django template syntax, none of them will provide any kind of GUI functionality.

Answer (score 0):

As far as IDEs go, Jetbrains is good, Eclipse has pretty decent python support, though I'm a big fan of sublime texts smart simplicity.

As for GUI stuff, perhaps rethink a little here. Django is a web framework that deals best with transactional interaction. It fires you a web page, you fire it a response. The system isn't really a good fit to GUI stuff. Thats not to say it can't play a part. Instead consider splitting it into a client/server product. Both TastyPie and Django Rest Framework are good options for building a RESTful API that can be interrogated by a remote client. You can then build the client using either one of the visual studio suites, or delphi, or if your looking to stay within the python mothership, perhaps PyQT/PySide (Which include a visual form designer) would be more up your alley. I guess you could build djangos ORM into an app (Although personally I'd use SQLAlchemy for that as its more decoupled than djangos ORM), but I'd warn that direct network access to databases isn't generally held to be wise for obvious security reasons, and you need to have a have a hard think about the threading implications if your gui toolkit is multithreaded, because Djangos ORM isn't built with the assumption it'll need to deal with multiple threads over single objects. My 0.02c is use Django to build an API and PyQT (or whateer your comfortable with) for the front end.

Answer (score 0):

GUI is a term more for desktops, frontend is for web, for more see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface.

Try any [HTML5 WISWYG editor](https://www.devsaran.com/blog/top-7-html5-editors-web-development) to make  frontend (probably responsive) design.

More no this look in https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148489/how-to-develop-front-end-ui-for-my-django-website